# PostgreSQL: List databases user has privilege to connect

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

**How do I list only the databases the user has `CONNECT` privilege on PostgreSQL?**

For instance, `user1` has access to database `db1` and `user2` has access to `db2`.

When each of these users login/connect to their databases and they need to retrieve the databases list they can connect with.

Here is what i've done so far:

Created two databases `db1` and `db2` on my new prostgreSQL server.

```
CREATE DATABASE db1
    WITH 
    OWNER = admin
    ENCODING = 'WIN1252'
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

CREATE DATABASE db2
    WITH 
    OWNER = admin
    ENCODING = 'WIN1252'
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

I've also created two new users (other than admin) `user1` and `user2`

```
CREATE USER user1 WITH LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'user1';
CREATE USER user2 WITH LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'user2';
```

Then I ran the following queries to make `user1` as owner of `db1` and `user2` as the onwer of `db2`

```
BEGIN;
ALTER DATABASE db1 owner to user1;
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE db1 FROM public; 
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db1 TO user1;
COMMIT

BEGIN;
ALTER DATABASE db2 owner to user2;
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE db2 FROM public; 
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db2 TO user2;
COMMIT
```

This way `user1` cannot connect to `db2` and `user2` cannot connect to `db1`.

Running this query

```
SELECT datname , (aclexplode(datacl)).grantor,
       (aclexplode(datacl)).grantee,
       (aclexplode(datacl)).privilege_type,
       (aclexplode(datacl)).is_grantable FROM pg_database
```

gives this:

```
 datname | grantor | grantee | privilege_type | is_grantable
---------+---------+---------+----------------+--------------
 db1     |   16386 |       0 | TEMPORARY      | f
 db1     |   16386 |   16386 | CREATE         | f
 db1     |   16386 |   16386 | TEMPORARY      | f
 db1     |   16386 |   16386 | CONNECT        | f
 db2     |   16387 |       0 | TEMPORARY      | f
 db2     |   16387 |   16387 | CREATE         | f
 db2     |   16387 |   16387 | TEMPORARY      | f
 db2     |   16387 |   16387 | CONNECT        | f
(8 rows)
```

*omitted template1 and template0 from results*

**How do I interpret if `user1` has access to CONNECT `db2` or not?**

**Is there any other way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aclexplode().grantee` can be joined to [`pg_user.usesysid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-user.html) to get the name of the user.

However, the simpler solution is to use the [access privilege inquiry functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE).

To check if `user1` can connect to `db2`:

```
SELECT has_database_privilege('user1', 'db2', 'CONNECT')
```

To list all databases which are accessible to `user1`:

```
SELECT datname
FROM pg_database
WHERE has_database_privilege('user1', datname, 'CONNECT')
```

Comment: Excellent. Is there also a way to avoid the templates coming up in the result?

Comment: silly me. I found the way to exclude the templates. Adding filter to where clause worked: `and datistemplate = false;`